# COUNT with CASE WHEN is showing the same result when using division

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have the following query which returns the sold products:

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN sold_flag =1 
AND product_category_ = 7
AND year(sold_date) = 2021
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM fact_sales;
```

I want to calculate the percentage of the sold products comparing to all products for product_category =7 :

```
   SELECT
     (COUNT(CASE WHEN sold_flag =1 
    AND product_category_ = 7
    AND year(sold_date) = 2021
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
    COUNT(CASE WHEN product_category_ = 7
    AND year(sold_date) = 2021
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 100
    FROM fact_sales;
```

I get the result as 100, while I execute each query separately they don't have the same result.

Comment: integer division - try multiplying your first count by `100.0` (*not* 100) and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: also your second count statement might missing a `when`.  If the 100.0 fixes your problem, you can replace it with a `cast`/`convert` to do the same thing more formally.

Comment: I tried what you provided but it is still the same issue

Comment: Try using SUM rather than COUNT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count()` counts both 0 and 1s, it does not counts `NULL`s.

Use `ELSE null` instead of `ELSE 0`

OR

use `SUM()` instead of `count()`